# iOS - Simple Resampling audio function for iOS

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing, vdsp, novocaine

I am using Novocaine for recording audio, for an audio processing iOS app.
I have a custom audio filter, which I apply after recording.
Now I want the Audio to be resampled at 8kHz.
So basically I need a simple module/function in which I pass the audio data buffer, and simply get a Resampled Audio.

I have looked on internet but found no generic resampling audio data solution as per my requirement for iOS.

Please help me, I shall be very thankful to you.